# Is there a practical way to see the actual rulings/reasons/considerations that resulted in the litigation bars in effect against vexatious litigants?

Tags: england-and-wales

There is a register of bans available at https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vexatious-litigants, but it is just the barest list of names. Where can one find any more details on each of these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

> Where can one find any more details on each of these cases?

The orders will be on file at the court and, unless sealed, would be available for public viewing. You can also search online databases for terms such as "vexatious litigant" or the name of the person for the written reasons.

> Is it practical...

This is asking for an opinion. All I can say is that I have done it via both methods.

Comment: Okay so it is possible but does that make it practical? A case reference to punch into bailii/canlii would seem preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The definition of a vexatious litigant is one who *habitually* uses lawsuits for improper purposes.  As such, there will be court records of all these lawsuits which led to this determination.  You simply search the court records for those suits.

The government is not going to *summarize the reason*, because that would them creating editorial content about the litigant which is deleterious to their reputation. Which puts the litigant in a very bad, and basically unfair position.  *Their hands are tied, they can't very well sue for defamation without getting permission of the very same government making the satatement!*

It's bad form to be unfair to people you have barred for being unfair, as it undercuts your own claim of their unfairness.

Comment: Yes, but surely there could at least be references in the list to the original court decisions that had resulted in the reasons. It's kind of like how justice must be seen to be done, and that is no less true of someone who loses their appeal against public execution in the court of last resort, where it's the end of the line and they can no longer challenge the profound denigration of their legacy. But the reasons and processes and rationales for the decision are still public and no less easily available.